# How can I go from "I can express myself" to "I can express myself in multiple ways"?

Tags: learning-methods, grammar, speaking, writing

Most of the time, I can express myself appropriately in Chinese (speaking and writing).  The catch is, my language would sound more fluent if I were able to say essentially the same thing in multiple ways (different word order, grammar structure, word choice).

I'm trying to figure out how I could improve on this aspect.  I've been practicing/drilling Chinese with ChatGPT recently, so it'd be great if I could find a way to use ChatGPT to help practice flexibly constructing sentences.  But I'm open to other options too.

**Question**: How can I go from "I can express myself" to "I can express myself in multiple ways"?

Comment: I assume in multiple ways is an addition to the original and would also be an addition in Chinese. I am not even sure that in English everything can be said in "multiple ways".